# How to get contents of $_GET

Tags: php

I'm using GET to process my search form and working with pagination I need to resubmit the $_GET params as my target URL.  Is there an easy way to build my new target URL from the contents of $_GET or do I need to use something like explode or simply iterate through the $_GET array?

Basically I'm looking for a shortcut or a better method of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the query string submitted to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the $_GET by using the syntax below:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$val) {
  // build your URL here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the query string, then `http_build_query()` would be handy to create another query string out of present one using altered $_GET array (or it's copy)